# Rails 3.1 - Fields With Errors

Tags: css, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using Rails helper methods to build a form, and using validations.

Whenever one of these validations fails, rails wraps the corresponding inputs and labels in a field_with_errors tag. Which is fine.

However, for some reasons rails is wrapping both the input AND the label in different divs, making styling really hard:

eg:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors">...label...</div>
    <div class="field_with_errors">..input ...</div>
</div>
```

and what I need is:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors">...label & input...</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to replace the divs with spans, which don't break formatting as they're not block level elements. To do so, put this somewhere in an initializer:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  "<span class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe 
end
```

Another way would be to simply make the original divs not display as block level elements, with this line in your CSS file:

```
.field_with_errors { display: inline-block; }
```

but this is not fully supported by [some of the older browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) (looking at you IE6 and 7).

Comment: Thanks. This one with escaping double quotes works. This http://railscasts.com/episodes/39-customize-field-error doesn't work anymore...